# Is it possible to detect if a label is about to over run in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

In my application I have a `UILabel` that holds an expanding number of entries so for example every time the user presses a button a "1" is appended on the end of the label. 
However I would like to be able to detect when adding an additional entry to the label will cause it to overrun the size of it's container and become an ugly "111..." label with the desired behaviour being something along the lines of :

```
int maximumLengthBeforeOverrun = self.maximumLengthBeforeLabelOverrun;
if(label.text.length > maximumLengthBeforeOverrun) {
    NSString * newLabel = [label.text substringTo:label.text.length - 1]
    label.text = newLabel;
}
label.text = [label.text appendWithString:toAppend]
```

My question is there some method in the IOS SDK that will do this for me? Or should I be using a different approach to display the information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `sizeWithFont`

```
NSString *str = @"Test String";
CGSize size = [str sizeWithFont:label.font];
```

Then use size to compare it with label.frame.size

Answer (score 1):

sizeWithFont was deprecated in iOS 7 so you need to use sizeWithAttributes

```
NSString *str = @"Test String";
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: label.font};
CGSize size = [str sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
```